# How to get resource usage from docker build command

Tags: docker, memory, cpu

I need to track the memory and CPU usage of BUILDING (NOT RUNNING) a docker container.

I have tried using psrecord (along with the include children option) on the PID for the terminal I run docker build on, but it is returning values as if I am not doing anything on that terminal. I was informed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76335665/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-docker-build-command) that psrecord is telling the truth because docker is asking the docker daemon to do stuff on its behalf. But resources are actually being consumed when python libraries, etc are being installed.

How do I track the memory and CPU usage resulting from docker build?